# NameError after attempt to apply imported modules

Tags: python, import, nameerror

I have a slightly lengthy and repetitive program where I import other modules into it to then put in all the information gathered together into a completed sentence. The issue I am having is everything I had defined before moving onto the next part, shows up as a NameError.

Here's the code:

```
 import number 
 print("Hello! \nWhat is your name?") 
 myName = input()
 print("Well, " + myName + ", I think it is time for us to play a
 little game.") 
 print("First, I need to know how old you are. Please
 type your age using only numbers.") 
 while True:
     age = input()
     try:
         if age:
             age = float(age)
             print("Great!\nNow, where do you live " + myName + "?")
             import Place
     except ValueError:
         print("I'm sorry, I did not understand your answer. Please only use digits and no decimals.")
```

Here is the Place module:

```
 print("As a reminder, I am unable to tell the difference between
 places and anything else you respond with. You can make me sound
 silly, or you can just answer the question so everything makes sense
 in the end!") 
 place = input() 
 print("Alright!\nNow what is your
 gender?") 
 print("While today's society has more than two ways to
 describe gender, please only use male or female for the sake of
 simplicity!") 
 while True:
     gender = input()
     if gender == "male":
         print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
         import Answer
     if gender == "MALE":
         print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
         import Answer
     if gender == "Male":
         print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
         import Answer
     if gender == "FEMALE":
         print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
         import Answer
     if gender == "Female":
         print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
         import Answer
     if gender == "female":
         print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
         import Answer
     else:
         print("Are you a male or female?")
```

Here is the Answer module:

```
while True:
    print("Did I get everything correct?\nPlease say yes or no.")
    answer = input()
    if answer == "Yes":
        print("Great! Thanks for playing!")
        break
    if answer == "yes":
        print("Great! Thanks for playing!")
        break
    if answer == "YES":
        print("Great! Thanks for playing!")
        break
    elif answer == "no":
        print("Okay! To make sure I avoid any errors, we must start from the beginning!")
        import Self_Story
    elif answer == "No":
        print("Okay! To make sure I avoid any errors, we must start from the beginning!")
        import Self_Story
    elif answer == "NO":
        print("Okay! To make sure I avoid any errors, we must start from the beginning!")
        import Self_Story
    else:
        print("I'm sorry, I did not understand that.")
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Maddiefayee/Documents/Self_Story.py", line 12, in <module>
    import Place
  File "/Users/Maddiefayee/Documents/Place.py", line 20, in <module>
    print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
NameError: name 'myName' is not defined
```

Comment: As this was posted I believe I messed up the formatting for posting the code, apologies, still really new at this!

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Click edit, paste your code, and press Control + K (or Cmd + K). While you're at it, please post a MVCE.

Comment: In which line are you exactly getting the error? Also, could you paste the error message?

Comment: if you do `gender = input().lower().strip()` you can cut down a lot of the repetition, since then any casing of "Male" or "MALE" or "MaLE" etc will convert to lowercase `"male"`...

Comment: Also, if the "Answer Module has nothing to do with the rest of the code", then why do you need to import it at all?

Comment: I see what you are asking, I'll import it. And thank you David for a way to take down the repetition!

Comment: These probably should be *function*, not modules...

Comment: Got it, and fixed that!

Comment: No, you didn't. They're still *modules* as you're executing them. What I'm saying is that they should probably *not* be modules, but they should be functions all within the same module.

Comment: So I should combine all of them under one instead of importing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd convert your "modules" to functions, and put them all within the same module (this really isn't a very big program, nor any reason I see to have separate modules for this). Then, you can run this module and the entire program will run as intended:

```
def GetNameAge():
    print("Hello! \nWhat is your name?") 
    myName = input()
    print("Well, " + myName + ", I think it is time for us to play a little game.") 
    print("""First, I need to know how old you are. Please
    type your age using only numbers.""") 
    while True:
        age = input()
        try:
            if age:
                age = str(float(age))
                return myName, age
        except ValueError:
            print("I'm sorry, I did not understand your answer. Please only use digits and no decimals.")

def GetPlaceGender():
    print("""As a reminder, I am unable to tell the difference between
    places and anything else you respond with. You can make me sound
    silly, or you can just answer the question so everything makes sense
    in the end!""") 
    place = input() 
    print("""Alright!\nNow what is your gender?\nWhile today's society has more than two ways to describe gender, 
    please only use male or female for the sake of simplicity!""") 
    while True:
        gender = input()
        gender = gender.lower().strip()
        if gender in ["male","female","m","f"]:
            return "male" if gender[0] == "m" else "female", place
        else:
            print("Are you a male or female?")   

def GetAnswer():
    while True:
        print("Did I get everything correct?\nPlease say yes, no, or exit.")
        answer = input()
        answer = answer.lower().strip()
        if answer in ["yes","y"]:
            print("Great! Thanks for playing!")
            return True
        elif answer in ["no","n"]:
            print("Okay! To make sure I avoid any errors, we must start from the beginning!")
            return False
        elif answer == "exit":
            return True
        else:
            print("I'm sorry, I did not understand that.")

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    while True:
        myName, age = GetNameAge()
        print("Great!\nNow, where do you live, " + myName + "?")
        gender, place = GetPlaceGender()
        print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
        if GetAnswer(): break
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you import something, variables don't carry over. Instead, you should say this:

```
def place():
    print("As a reminder, I am unable to tell the difference between
places and anything else you respond with. You can make me sound
silly, or you can just answer the question so everything makes sense
in the end!") 
place = input() 
print("Alright!\nNow what is your
gender?") 
print("While today's society has more than two ways to
describe gender, please only use male or female for the sake of
simplicity!") 
while True:
    gender = input()
    if gender == "male":
        print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + "    years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
     import Answer
 if gender == "MALE":
     print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
     import Answer
 if gender == "Male":
     print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
     import Answer
 if gender == "FEMALE":
     print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
     import Answer
 if gender == "Female":
     print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
     import Answer
 if gender == "female":
     print("Your name is " + myName + " and you are " + age + " years old. You are a " + gender + " and you live in " + place + "!")
     import Answer
 else:
     print("Are you a male or female?")
def answer():
   while True:
   print("Did I get everything correct?\nPlease say yes or no.")
   answer = input()
   if answer == "Yes":
       print("Great! Thanks for playing!")
       break
   if answer == "yes":
       print("Great! Thanks for playing!")
       break
   if answer == "YES":
       print("Great! Thanks for playing!")
       break
   elif answer == "no":
       print("Okay! To make sure I avoid any errors, we must start from    the beginning!")
       import Self_Story
   elif answer == "No":
       print("Okay! To make sure I avoid any errors, we must start from    the beginning!")
       import Self_Story
   elif answer == "NO":
       print("Okay! To make sure I avoid any errors, we must start from    the beginning!")
       selfStory()
   else:
       print("I'm sorry, I did not understand that.")
def selfStory():
   import number 
   print("Hello! \nWhat is your name?") 
   myName = input()
   print("Well, " + myName + ", I think it is time for us to play a
   little game.") 
   print("First, I need to know how old you are. Please
   type your age using only numbers.") 
   while True:
       age = input()
       try:
           if age:
               age = float(age)
               print("Great!\nNow, where do you live " + myName + "?")
               place()
       except ValueError:
           print("I'm sorry, I did not understand your answer. Please    only use digits and no decimals.")
selfStory()
```